# Query com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Olá , como ficaria em lavarel um select como este exemplo:

```
SELECT DADO FROM TABELA WHERE ID = '123' AND (FLAG IS NULL OR FLAG = 0)
```

Não consegui encontrar exemplos parecidos por ai :(

Comment: Você pode ver mais sobre como obter dados do banco de dados com laravel na documentação https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#retrieving-results (usando a classe DB) ou https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#retrieving-models (usando Eloquent ORM)

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que um dos exemplos abaixo conseguem te ajudar:

```
# Utilizando a classe DB 
$users = DB::table('users')
           ->where('id', '=', 123)
           ->where(function ($query) {
               $query->whereNull('flag')
                     ->orWhere('flag', '=', 0);
           })
           ->select('name')
           ->get();

# Utilizando o Model User
$users = User::where('id', '=', 123)
             ->where(function ($query) {
                 $query->whereNull('flag')
                     ->orWhere('flag', '=', 0);
             })
             ->select('name')
             ->get();
```

Comment: Pode começar a query com `Users::query()`.

Comment: É uma opção também, vou editar e colocar as duas opções.